# Concurrently setup fix

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, concurrently

[Concurrently setup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPZns.png)
Please help me out to fix this error.
I am using concurrently dev dependencies to run server and client site simultaneously but its not working as you can see in this photo.

Comment: Could You use code snippet to present Your console error instead of print screen  please ?

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
"concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run start:client\" \"npm run start:server\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `console` "says" that, It looks like You have a `path` issue in the first place, not [concurrently](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently) module.

The solution is very simple :

1. Please Add **C:\Windows\System32** to the `global PATH environment` variable.